# Convert difference in milliseconds to .MaxValue back to Date/Time

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, timestamp

For a rowkey on Azure `TableStorage` entities following prefix is used:

```
DateTime.MaxValue.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds
```

As far as I know should this `timestamp` act as a kind of "sorter" so that newer entities are on top of an list. So, this shown code line creates (as I can imagine) the amount of milliseconds of the current date/time till the `DateTime.MaxValue`.

Is there a simple and safe way, to convert this amount of milliseconds "back" to the date/time when the `timestamp` was created? I´m not so familiar with date/time conversions...

Comment: I would Keep It Simple: is there a reason for not using DateTime.UctNow? it would be as sortable as your difference in Milliseconds from DateTime.MaxValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DateTime.MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

> equivalent to 23:59:59.9999999 UTC, December 31, 9999 in the
>   Gregorian calendar, exactly one 100-nanosecond tick before 00:00:00
>   UTC, January 1, 10000.

Thus, considering roughly 10,000 years, you have:

```
10,000 x 365 x 24 x 60 x 60 x 1000 = 315,360,000,000,000 //Note 15-digit
```

And the [double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/678hzkk9.aspx) precision is at least 15-digit. In other words, as long as you use the first 15 digit of your `TotalMilliseconds` as the timestamp, then it should be fine.

I recommend to cast it to [long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) whose integer precision is:

```
–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 //note, more than 15-digit
```

And then use `ToString("D15")` as unique timestamp:

```
long val = (long)DateTime.MaxValue.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds;
string timestamp = val.ToString("D15");
```

And to convert back, you could cast it back to `double` and use `AddMilliseconds` with negative sign from max.

```
double db = Convert.ToDouble(timestamp);
DateTime dt = DateTime.MaxValue;
dt.AddMilliseconds(-db); //this will give you the datetime back with milliseconds precision
```

Then you will get precision up to your milliseconds.